# How can I extract the star ratings from an icon element that only has class using Python beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrap the rating from a [website](https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=live+plants&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=..search.go.), but the rating was a few "i" elements grouped together to form the numbers of star shown in the picture rating.png.

Therefore, I tried to check the class attribute of the element and then compare it, if matches, append the result into an list called ratings.

I have found out the attributes of the elements which is:

```
<div class="mdmmT _32vUv">
   <i class="_9-ogB Dy1nx"></i>
   <i class="_9-ogB Dy1nx"></i>
   <i class="_9-ogB Dy1nx"></i>
   <i class="_9-ogB Dy1nx"></i>
   <i class="_9-ogB fqfC4"></i> #these are the rating elements starting with 9-ogB
<span class="qzqFw">(7)</span></div>
```

I was using the code below to compare the element attribute and append but it doesn't work as I've thought, looking for any open suggestions and guidance. Thank you for your time!

```
for e in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'_6uN7R'}):
    f = e.find('div', attrs={'class':'mdmmT _32vUv'})
    rating = f.find('i')[4]
    if hasattr(rating, "_9-ogB fqfC4"):
        ratings.append("4.5")
    else:
        ratings.append("test")
```

I need to get the rating of every product, but the result return empty list []

Answer (score 1):

The website is dynamic and bs4 can't render JavaScript.So you can try bs4 along with Selenium.

**Example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

driver.get('https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=live+plants&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=..search.go.')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")

for e in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'_6uN7R'}):
    rating = e.select_one('span.qzqFw').get_text(strip=True) if e.select_one('span.qzqFw') else None
    print(rating)
```

**Output:**

```
(380)
(598)
(150)
(396)
(126)
(31) 
(57) 
(106)
(5)  
(39) 
(26) 
(35) 
(240)
(24) 
(39) 
(15) 
None 
None 
(8)  
(55)
(10)
None
(195)
(4)
(214)
(43)
(15)
(113)
(362)
(56)
(22)
(7)
(0)
(2)
(10)
None
(7)
(1)
(5)
(2)
```

*Update:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

driver.get('https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=live+plants&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=..search.go.')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
token = soup.select_one('#X-CSRF-TOKEN')['content']

api_url="https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&ajax=true&from=input&isFirstRequest=true&page=2&q=live%20plants&spm=..search.go."

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-csrf-token': token,
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  
   }
s=requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
req = s.get(api_url)
for v in req.json().get('mods').get('listItems'):
    rating = v['ratingScore'] if v['ratingScore']  else 'No rating'
    rating_score = f"{rating:.2f}"
    print(rating_score)
```

Comment: thanks for your time, unfortunately it didnt work out and returned:   rating = e.select_one('.fqfC4').get_text(strip=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'  <<  I believe they used I element and style it in another CSS that makes it look like that, there is no text inside the element therefore NoneType

Comment: @chang kinwai, please see the updated ResultSet.

Comment: thanks for the code Fazlul, but sorry to say you are looking at the wrong elements, I wish to get the ratings, not the sold amount. Hope that helps!